# Complex number C++ implementation performance

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc

I have a program which spends a massive time doing complex exponential calculus.
It currently uses `cexp` from the C99 math library. (I will refer to it as complex)

But I must have the program running under windows too.

ATM I use MinGW but if it is better performance-wise I'd like to switch to MSVC.
However, MSVC doesn't provide C99 support so it has to be the C++ Complex template-class implementation (I will refer to it as Complex); also included is the _complex typedef but there isn't `cexp` so I have to use sin and cos to compute it "by hand".

So I wanted to know, which is the better, performance-wise :

- Staying in MinGW and using complex. I studied the source code of libc6 and it looks like there are calls to sin and cos anyway.
- Going MSVC, using the Complex implementation
- Going MSVC, using the _complex implementation

Also, is it worth it to keep complex (for Unix OSes) if I go Complex or _complex ? 
Or will the difference in performance be irrelevant (Using gcc 4.7 with -O3 and MSVC with /O2?)

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you doing that needs so many calls to `xexp()`?

Comment: A fourier transform but I can't use any FFT library. And I'm at the deadline of a project so it's just "icing on the cake" basically.

Comment: @user1495627 Ha! I suspected at such. If you're doing an FFT, you should be caching your twiddle factors instead of computing them over and over again.

Comment: Basically, I can change the implementation details but not the algorithm (butterfly) and it doesn't use caching :/

Comment: You don't need to change the algorithm to cache twiddle factors. If you're going to implement any FFT and care even the least bit about performance, the first thing you do is precompute and cache the twiddle factors. The performance gains from caching twiddle factors will likely dwarf anything you can gain from a faster `cexp()`.

Comment: Why only MSVC considered? If performance is important it might be worth trying Intel compiler.

Comment: You can still look at the source and docs of a package like [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/), even if you can't use it directly.

Comment: If compatibility source code wise is important, perhaps use CygWin's GCC (hopefully the same or similar version across the board).